# Views all data export included image name/path

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I have a View. In my view Image, Product Id, etc are shown. I want to export all the data of that View in the form of doc file or CSV or excel sheet, in the tabular form if it store the data in the form of doc or csv.

My condition is that : For image field atleast image name/image path stored.

Is there any module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)  module.

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft
> - XLS
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - XML.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaMohan.. I already use this module, through this module In place of image field, blank is shown.

Comment: @samzha make sure to display 'image link' instead of 'Image' at views output

Comment: I try to configure some setting.

Comment: I had try this module. Actually Image is only show in 'doc'. I want to fetch in the form of excel sheet.